# How to fix "refusing to merge unrelated histories"? I have tried "git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories"

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am trying to pull everything from my dev branch to master but I am getting "Already up to date". So when I tried to merge them together, i get, "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories". Can someone please help me.

I have tried git reset --hard

iwithman~/Programming/ibusiness-card-web$:git merge wip269 origin/master

fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

iwithman~/Programming/ibusiness-card-web$:git branch

- master

  wip269

iwithman~/Programming/ibusiness-card-web$:git merge wip269

fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

iwithman~/Programming/ibusiness-card-web$:git pull wip269

fatal: 'wip269' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use `--allow-unrelated-histories`, as [morty answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57437199/1256452).  But watch out: this may not do what you want.  It depends on what you want, and what's in the two commits you'll choose this way.

`git merge` works by comparing the *merge base* commit with the two particular other commits that you select.  You select one of the two commits you want to use by checking it out:

```
git checkout master
```

and the other with an argument to `git merge`:

```
git merge wip269
```

for instance.

The *merge base*, however, is determined by the history, and history, in Git, consists of the commits in the repository, as linked by those commits themselves.  This is where the command is failing, because the histories are not related to each other: there *is no merge base commit*.

If the histories *were* related, this:

```
          A--B--...--H   <-- master
         /
...--o--*
         \
          P--Q--...--W   <-- wip269
```

might be a good way to draw the commit graph.  From this drawing, you could see that the history in `master` starts (or ends) at commit `H` and works backwards to `A`, and then to commit `*` and further back; and history in `wip269` starts (or end) at commit `W`, then works back to `P` and on to `*` and further back.

Commit `*` would then be the merge base.  The merge base is defined as the best common commit.  The best one is obviously `*`—commits that come before it would work too, but it seems better to stick with the one closest to the two branch-ends you started from.  The way `git merge` works is to compare the files in the merge base to the files in your current commit—here `H`—to see what *you* changed, then compare those same files in the same merge base to the files in *their* commit (`W`) to see what *they* changed.  Having found what you both changed, Git can combine the changes.

**The problem here is that your history does not look anything like this.**  It probably looks something like this:

```
A--B--...--H   <-- master (HEAD)

P--Q--...--W   <-- wip269
```

That is, starting at `H` and working backwards, Git eventually arrives at commit `A`, which is a *root commit:* it has no previous history.  Meanwhile, starting at `W` and working backwards, Git eventually arrives at commit `P`, which is also a root commit.  *There is no shared commit that is on both branches.*

Using `--allow-unrelated-histories` tells `git merge`: *OK, if there's no common commit, play a pretend game that there is: pretend that there is a common commit that contains no files at all, and use that as the merge base.*

This means that *what you changed* is: you invented every file from scratch.  Meanwhile, what they changed is that they, too, invented every file from scratch.

Where the invented files have *different names*, Git will take the new files.  Where they have the *same* names, Git will declare an `add/add conflict` and leave you to figure out what should go in the file with that name.

If and when you resolve all such conflicts and commit—or if there are no conflicts—Git will make a new merge commit whose parents are both `H` and `W`:

```
A--B--...--H
            \
             X   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
P--Q--...--W   <-- wip269
```

and now commits `P` through `W` are on *both* branches.  Commits `A` through `H`, plus `X`, are (only) on `master`.  If you move the name `wip269` so that it, too, points to new commit `X`, all 17 commits will be on both branches; or you can delete the name `wip269` now, if you're done with it, after which all commits are only on `master`.

#### Side note on `git pull`

All `git pull` does is run `git fetch`, then immediately run a second Git command.  The second command is usually—and is in your case—`git pull`.  So you *can* do this with `git pull` (which can pass `--allow-unrelated-histories` to its `git merge`), but you might as well do it with `git merge` at this point—you've probably already done any necessary `fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

dev and master branches have 'unrelated histories' which means they have no common base by default. 
git merge does not allow two branches with unrelated histories to be merged to prevent parallel histories.

You can use `--allow-unrelated-histories` to force the merge.

Comment: iwithman~/Programming/ibusiness-card-web$:git --allow-unrelated-histories master 

unknown option: --allow-unrelated-histories

usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]

           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--
info-path]

           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]

           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

Comment: That is what came up.